# VB.net - TcpListener based Web server

Tags: vb.net

I built in vb.net one webserver from this how-to: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0400__Socket-Network/TcpListenerbasedWebserver.htm

The code works fine reads the html but I can not understand why not showing images. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading the HTML of a webpage will absolutely never download any kind of secondary elements/files, including images.

In order to get the images, you'll need to get the images URL and download them separately.